# FFMPEG: Error while opening encoder - when resizing

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to resize a video so that the height is 240px.

Here is the code I used:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf scale=-1:240 -acodec mp3 -vcodec libx264 output.mp4
```

The error I received was this:

> Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect
>   parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height

Specifically, here is the complete response:

```
> [libx264 @ 042e0200] width not divisible by 2 (427x240) Output #0,
> mp4, to 'output_240p.mp4':   Metadata:
>     major_brand     : isom
>     minor_version   : 512
>     compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
>     encoder         : Lavf53.24.2
>     Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264, none, q=2-31, 128 kb/s, SAR 1280:1281 DAR 0:0 , 25 fps (default)
>     Metadata:
>       creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
>       handler_name    : VideoHandler
>       encoder         : Lavc56.57.100 libx264
>     Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3, 0 channels, 128 kb/s (default)
>     Metadata:
>       creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
>       handler_name    : SoundHandler
>       encoder         : Lavc56.57.100 libmp3lame Stream mapping:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))   Stream #0:1 ->
> #0:1 (aac (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame)) Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate,
> rate, width or height
```

If I use the below code, it works great, except then I can't keep on using my aspect ratio:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -s 320x240 -acodec mp3 -vcodec libx264 output.mp4
```

Any idea what is going on here? Thanks!

Comment: This question is off-topic because it isn't code. You're just running the program.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf scale=-1:240 -acodec mp3 -vcodec libx264
>   output.mp4

Use -2:240, not -1:240. H264 requires that all dimensions are multiples of the chroma subsampling (in your case, 2 in both dimensions), so both sizes need to be multiples of 2.

[edit] and yes, this question should probably be asked on superuser, not here.

Comment: Thanks Ronald! I was away for a bit and it also occurred to me later that the "-1" might be causing the issue when I remembered the ` width not divisible by 2 (427x240)` error. I will post in superuser next time ;)